# Connection refused error in java using Google map API with eclipse IDE while the same URL is giving me the result in browsers

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am using the bellow code for a simple java application using Google map APIs to get a JASON response.

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.mapsengine.MapsEngine;
import com.google.api.services.mapsengine.MapsEngineRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.mapsengine.model.Feature;
import com.google.api.services.mapsengine.model.FeaturesListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.mapsengine.model.GeoJsonPoint;
import java.io.IOException;

/** Java "Hello, world!" example using the client library */
public class HelloWorld {
  static final String SAMPLE_TABLE_ID = "12421761926155747447-06672618218968397709";
  static final String PUBLIC_API_KEY = "**MYAPIKEY**";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();

    // This request initializer will ensure the API key is sent with every HTTP request.
MapsEngineRequestInitializer apiKeyInitializer =
    new MapsEngineRequestInitializer(PUBLIC_API_KEY);

MapsEngine engine = new MapsEngine.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, null)
    .setMapsEngineRequestInitializer(apiKeyInitializer)
    .setApplicationName("Google-MapsEngineSample/1.0")
    .build();

readFeaturesFromTable(engine);
  }

  public static void readFeaturesFromTable(MapsEngine me) throws IOException {
// Query the table for offices in WA that are within 100km of Perth.
FeaturesListResponse featResp =  me.tables().features().list(SAMPLE_TABLE_ID)
    .setVersion("published")
    .setWhere("State='WA' AND ST_DISTANCE(geometry,ST_POINT(115.8589,-31.9522)) < 100000")
    .execute();

for (Feature feat : featResp.getFeatures()) {
  System.out.println(
      "Properties: " + feat.getProperties().toString() + "\n\t" +
      "Name: " + feat.getProperties().get("Fcilty_nam") + "\n\t" +
      "Geometry Type: " + feat.getGeometry().getType());

  if (feat.getGeometry() instanceof GeoJsonPoint)  {
    GeoJsonPoint point = (GeoJsonPoint) feat.getGeometry();
    System.out.println("\t" +
        "Longitude: " + point.getCoordinates().get(0) + ", " +
        "Latitude: " +  point.getCoordinates().get(1));
  } else {
    System.out.println("Only points are expected in this table!");
    return;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I have no error in this, as i have followed every instruction to configure the eclipse IDE for Google map APIs and used jars for compiling. (By referring this [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/hello-world).)

While Debugging this code in debugging mode it raises the error saying 
**java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect**
from the code

`FeaturesListResponse featResp =  me.tables().features().list(SAMPLE_TABLE_ID)
    .setVersion("published")
    .setWhere("State='WA' AND ST_DISTANCE(geometry,ST_POINT(115.8589,-31.9522)) < 100000")
    .execute();`

the URL produced by this is

> "https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/12421761926155747447-06672618218968397709/features?key=APIKEY&version=published&where=State%3D'WA'%20AND%20ST_DISTANCE(geometry,ST_POINT(115.8589,-31.9522))%20%3C%20100000"

If I paste the URL on some browser I am getting the Needed JASON response.

The same code is running in different environment.

Help me in solving this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Is the proxy configured in eclipse?

Comment: @SilentBob470 I have configured the proxy settings via (Menu) Windows>Preferences in that window in General>Network Connections I have Manual settings activated and configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting proxy on the HttpTransport before sending the request.

So I set the proxy before creating the object of type HttpTransport before sending the request.

The code is as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("YOUR PROXY IP", 80));   
HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport.Builder().setProxy(proxy).build();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
// This request initializer will ensure the API key is sent with every HTTP request.
MapsEngineRequestInitializer apiKeyInitializer =
    new MapsEngineRequestInitializer(PUBLIC_API_KEY);
}
```

Thanks for the responses.